# How to join multiple tables on a single column efficiently if you know the size of the tables?

Tags: sql, join

The tables I am joining are very big but I'm trying to think of the best way to write the query for the most efficient return speed.

The column is the same across all tables.

My query so far is:

```
select MRN.document from MRNtable MRN
left outer join MPItable MPI on MRN.document = MPI.document
where MPI.document is null
```

I need these results and then need to return the data associated to the document column from other tables in the most efficient manner possible.

I was thinking I would LEFT JOIN more 'document' columns from different tables (i.e. LASTNAMEtable and FIRSTNAMEtable) to MRNtable but wasn't sure there was a more efficient way to approach this.

Thoughts on solution for fastest query run-time?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create indexes for the column document

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do but still looking for query output recommendation.